# Android Application force closes when changing portrait to landscape

Tags: android, android-layout, android-view, android-xml

Here's my LogCat error:

```
java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.jc.jcpremiere/com.jc.jcpremiere.activity2}: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Wrong state class, expecting View State but received class android.os.Bundle instead. This usually happens when two views of different type have the same id in the same hierarchy. This view's id is id/aboutview. Make sure other views do not use the same id.
```

I'm getting this whenever I switch my phone from portrait to landscape. I have the layout for `/layout` and `/layout-land` containing only a view to display images, but on portrait, it can be pinched and zoomed and is on `centerInside`, and in landscape it's `fitxy`.

Here's my layout for portrait

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/rellayout"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <com.jc.jcpremiere.TouchImageView
        android:id="@+id/aboutview"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:adjustViewBounds="true"
        android:background="@color/White"
        android:scaleType="centerInside" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

And for my landscape

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/relativelayout1"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:orientation="horizontal" >

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/aboutview"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:background="@color/White"
        android:scaleType="fitXY" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your imageview's type is changing from potrait to landscape mode. Potrait uses **ImageView** while landscape uses **TouchImageView**. So your findViewById() method references to wrong view object in your landscape mode. Try changing the imageView's object to TouchImageView in your java class then I guess your potrait mode will crash.

Comment: Is there a way I can just use imageview on landscape and fit xy and on portrait I can use touchimageview center inside?

Answer (score 1):

You have `android:id="@+id/aboutview"` for both your `com.jc.jcpremiere.TouchImageView` and `ImageView` classes.

`android:id` must be unique, so no two components can have the same Android ids. Just change one Android id to something else and that should fix the problem.

Also, have either `TouchImageView` or `ImageView` for both portrait and landscape modes - not different types of View component for each mode.